# Filtering XML data with LinQ

Tags: windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml, where-clause

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app.

I have a list of Ids from a table and I want to filter a XML file that has all information about these table.

I have the following C# code:

```
var filteredData = 
    from c in loadedData.Descendants("gameDescription")
    where c.Attribute("gameType").Value == gameType &&
          c.Attribute("language").Value.Equals(language)
    select new SampleData.GamesDesc()
    {
        Id = uint.Parse(c.Attribute("game_id").Value),
        . . .
    };
```

If I have a `List<long> unfinishedGamesId`. I want to filer results getting every game that hasn't got an Id from unfinishedGamesId. Something like:

```
c.Attribute("game_id").Value != unfinishedGamesId[0] &&
c.Attribute("game_id").Value != unfinishedGamesId[1] &&
...
```

How can I add this to where clause?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do?  If you're wanting to include data whose values are in that list, the query would be:

```
var filteredData = 
    from c in loadedData.Descendants("gameDescription")
    where c.Attribute("gameType").Value == gameType &&
          c.Attribute("language").Value.Equals(language) &&
          unfinishedGamesId.Contains(c.Id)
    select new SampleData.GamesDesc()
    {
        Id = uint.Parse(c.Attribute("game_id").Value),
        . . .
    };
```

Assuming the Id value is the one you're getting with `uint.Parse`, this code should work:

```
var filteredData = 
   from c in loadedData.Descendants("gameDescription")
   where c.Attribute("gameType").Value == gameType &&
         c.Attribute("language").Value.Equals(language) &&
         unfinishedGamesId.Contains(uint.Parse(c.Attribute("game_id").Value))
   select new SampleData.GamesDesc()
   {
       Id = uint.Parse(c.Attribute("game_id").Value),
       . . .
   };
```

Doing the attribute lookup and parse twice is not very efficient, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Gotcha... since you're wanting values without entries in the list, using "!(unfinishedGamesId.Contains(...))" should do the trick.